# Como criar um plugin para a função $() do jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Notei que dá para criar *plugins* em várias funções do jQuery como AJAX, CSS (usando o `cssHooks`), `animate`, criar novas funções, entre outros. Mas pensei se é possível criar um *plugin* para a função de chamada do serviço, por exemplo:

$('26/08/1966')

Como exemplo o *plugin* poderia retornar uma *string* com a data mais detalha para usar com as funções do jQuery(html, css, each).

Entenda como uma forma de ensinar ao jQuery o que fazer com o string indicado no início.

Eu não sei se isso é possível, pesquisei e não achei nada relacionado (não sei se pesquisei certo) e seria interessante por que poderia facilitar o uso de um plugin que estou fazendo.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que pretende fazer?

Comment: Penso que você pode resolver o seu problema de outro modo. Não é bem por aí... Quero dizer: o que você pretende fazer provavelmente pode ser alcançado sem necessidade de "criar um plugin para a função de chamada do serviço", como você diz.

Comment: o string que ia na chamada do jQuery seria um url e o plugin também cria funções para mexer com um serviço de armazenamento na nuvem que eu criei.

Comment: No mínimo eu pensei que ele retornaria a string inicial mas em uns testes não deu muito certo, o valor sempre volta undefined

Comment: @IagoBruno Acontece que o jQuery interpreta `$(string)` como o uso de um seletor, ele não tem como diferenciar uma string cujo conteúdo é uma data da string cujo conteúdo é um seletor (ok, nesse caso até poderia, mas porque as sintaxes são suficientemente distintas). Isso seria um caso de [DWIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM), que na minha opinião é uma péssima prática [nesse contexto pelo menos]. Um exemplo são as planilhas eletrônicas, que tratam `1` como número, `1/2` como fração e `1/2/3` como data! Tipos numa linguagem de programação têm de ser inambíguos.

Comment: ninguém entendeu que o formato data era só um exemplo =p. Mas @mgibsonbr mas no caso se eu fosse fazer mesmo eu tentaria usar o context do jQuery, por ex: $('12/08/2013', 'date').getDay(). Mas obrigado pela resposta/comentário.

Answer (score 3):

### Background

O jQuery é especializado em lidar com elementos do DOM. Quando você faz algo como:

```
var x = $("seletor")
```

Ele cria um objeto que contém - dentre outras coisas - uma lista com zero ou mais elementos. Outras formas de criar esse objeto:

```
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var x = $([a, b, c]); // Lista com 3 elementos
var x = $(a);         // Lista com 1 elemento
var x = $();          // Lista com 0 elemento

var x = $("<div><span>Teste</span></div>"); // Cria um elemento e põe na lista
var x = $("<p>A</p><p>B</p><p>C</p>");      // Idem, para mais de um elemento
```

Todas as funções do "objeto jQuery" operam então em **listas de elementos do DOM**. Pode-se criar outras funções definidas pelo usuário, mas espera-se que as mesmas também atuem em listas de elementos do DOM:

```
$.fn.minhaFuncao = function() {
    // Aqui "this" é um objeto jQuery
    // Pode-se fazer isso:
    return this[0].value; // Retorna o valor do primeiro elemento
    // Ou isso:
    return this.each(function() { 
        this.value = 10; 
    }); // Faz todos elementos terem o valor 10, e retorna o próprio objeto (pra chaining)
};
```

### Resposta

Usar o jQuery em listas de objetos arbitrários é complicado, pois misturaria tipos de dados não compatíveis. Se você quisesse tratar de listas de datas (ou pior: de datas isoladas) todas as funções originais do jQuery poderiam ser chamadas nessas datas (causando erros, pois são tipos distintos) e da mesma forma as novas funções que você criasse também poderiam ser chamadas nas listas de elementos DOM (idem).

Misturar as duas coisas, portanto, não é boa ideia... Não conheço uma solução generalizada para fazer isso para "listas de tipo A", mas há bibliotecas como o [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) que usam um conceito semelhante ao do jQuery (fazer *wrap* em um objeto para introduzir suas próprias funções, inclusive com encadeamento) para realizar seus propósitos específicos.

Se a questão for adicionar métodos a **elementos individuais** de um tipo, basta mexer no seu protótipo:

```
Date.prototype.formatarData = function() {
    // "this" aqui é um objeto Date
}

var agora = new Date();
agora.formatarData(); // Chama seu método num objeto com a data atual
```

Há quem considere isso má prática (eu próprio, por exemplo) por "poluir o *namespace*", mas usado como moderação e cuidado pode ser uma boa opção...

Comment: Acho que o autor da pergunta não entendeu bem o uso do `JQuery` ou exemplificou de forma errada. jQuery é para interagir com o HTML, provavelmente ele está querendo algo do tipo `$('.data').formatarData();`, caso não seja isso não faz sentido usar JQuery

Comment: Eu entendo sobre o jQuery '-', o formato de data era só um exemplo. Olhando o código do jQuery não achei alguma parte que possibilitasse fazer isso, então, não tem solução para a minha pergunta. o/

Comment: Sim, o jQuery mexe especialmente com elementos do DOM, mas isso seria uma forma de "ensinar" ao jQuery o que fazer com o formato novo, mas não tem como mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

A syntax para criar um novo plugin que está na documentação so jQuery é:

```
$.fn.esverdear = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$("a").esverdear(); // Muda a cor de todos os elementos para verde.
```

Para trabalhar uma URL podia por exemplo fazer como coloquei em baixo. Note que dar retorno de um objeto jQuery (i.e. com wrapper `$()`) é importante para poder associar outros métodos como o `.each()` no exemplo:

```
var url = 'http://server/path/program?foo=bar&animal=gato';

$.fn.abrirURL = function (url) {
    var regex = /[?&;](.+?)=([^&;]+)/g;
    var match;
    params = [];
    if (url) {
        while (match = regex.exec(url)) {
            var param = {};
            param[match[1]] = decodeURIComponent(match[2]);
            params.push(param);
        }
        return $(params);
    }
};

$.fn.abrirURL(url).each(function () {
    console.log(this)
});

// Isto vai dar:
// Object {foo: "bar"} 
// Object {animal: "gato"}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/TQN42/)

Comment: Mas nesse caso, qual a vantagem de usar `$.fn.abrirURL` sobre, digamos, somente `function abrirURL`? Se sua função não opera em listas de elementos do DOM, não faz sentido escrevê-la como um plugin pro jQuery. Veja [minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15117/215) pra mais detalhes.

Comment: @mgibsonbr concordo consigo. Eu tentei responder à pergunta mostrando como criar um plugin. No caso de ser para trabalhar elementos não-DOM concordo que jQuery não é o mais indicado. É aí que por exemplo o MooTools brilha... `+1` para a sua resposta

Comment: Não sabia que o MooTools era bom pra isso, acho que vou tirar um tempo pra aprender a usá-lo então. Normalmente uso o Underscore.js - pelas suas funções de nível mais alto ao lidar com listas e objetos.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem, você está querendo criar uma função para formatar uma data através de `JQuery`. Se for isso, você pode fazer assim:

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.formatadata = function() {          
      //formata a data
   }; 
})( jQuery );

$('.data').formatadata();
```

Você pode ler mais sobre em [How to Create a Basic Plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Comment: Se a data a ser formatada está em um elemento do DOM, então sim, sua resposta está correta. Mas acho que não é bem isso que o OP está querendo, me parece que a ideia é usar o jQuery para manipular outros tipos de dados.