# Identificação do indice altera antes da hora JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, tempo-de-resposta, settimeout

Olá pessoal estou com um baita problema, seguinte estou precisando criar um elemento e enviar via ajax aguardar o retorno (done/fail) e executar uma ação nesse elemento, porém o envio e criação de elementos pode ser feito várias vezes seguidas e o retorno do ajax leva tempos diferentes de acordo com o tamanho do elemento enviado. O erro ocorre ao efetuar a ação no elemento após o retorno do ajax, pois o identificador do elemento já pode ter mudado caso tenha sido enviado outro elemento em seguida, tenho esse problema dentro de 3 locais, dentro do done e fail que a solução será a mesma pra ambos e tenho esse erro dentro de um setTimeOut que esta dentro de always.

Segue link do código/plugin: (obs.: é igual ao código que coloquei aqui em baixo no post) http://jsfiddle.net/mateusfmello/uog1k69p/

Código:  (obs.: simulação do erro)

```js
// elemento é um elemento do DOM

(function($){
  $.fn.plug = function(optionsPlugin) {
    var plugin = this;

    var defaultsPlugin = {
      debug : false
      elementos : true
    };

    confPlugin = $.extend(true, defaultsPlugin, optionsPlugin);

    var defaultsEnvio = {
      ajax : {
        type  : 'post',
        url   : '',
        data  : {}    
      }
    };


    if (confPlugin.elementos) {

      var idElement = 0;
      var elementos = new Array();
      // elemento é um elemento do DOM
      var criaElemento = function() {
        elementos.push('novo elemento com id: '+ idElement );
      };
      // elemento é um elemento do DOM
      var removeElemento = function(elemento){
        elemento.fadeOut(1000, function() {
          elemento.remove();
        });
      };
      // elemento é um elemento do DOM
      var statusElemento = function(elemento, status){

        if (status)
          elemento.addClass('ele-sucesso');
        else
          elemento.addClass('ele-erro');
      };
    };

    var enviaAjax = function(){

      $.ajax(
        confEnvio.ajax
      )
      .done(function(res) {
        if (confPlugin.elementos)
          statusElemento(elementos[idElement], true);
      })
      .fail(function(res) {
        if (confPlugin.elementos)
          statusElemento(elementos[idElement], false);
      })
      .always(function() {
        if (confPlugin.elementos)
          setTimeout(
            function(){
              removeElemento(elementos[idElement]);
            }
            , 2000
          );
      });
    };

    var confEnvio = {};

    plugin.enviar = function(optionsEnvio){

      confEnvio = $.extend(true, defaultsEnvio, optionsEnvio);

      if (confPlugin.elementos)
        criaElemento();

      enviaAjax();

      idElement++;
    };

    return this.each(function() {
      return plugin;
    }); 
  }; 
})(jQuery);

var enviaLa = $.fn.plug({debug:true});

enviaLa.enviar();
enviaLa.enviar();
```

**Pretendo liberar esse plugin no meu Github, quando fizer isso colocarei o link aqui nesse post.**

Comment: Qual é a ideia da ultima linha `return this.each(function () {`?

Comment: @Sergio a linha this.each eu vi em um tutorial de como criar plugins jquery, dai lá dizia que essa linha serve pra que possa ser feito isso element.addClass('lala').meuPlugin().removeClass('lala'); no caso se não tivesse isso teria que vai cada chamada de função em uma linha diferente.

Comment: Mateus, como apontei na minha resposta, basta passar o idElement como argumento de enviaAjax e atribuir o mesmo a uma variável local.

Comment: @TobyMosque sim fiz isso chegou a funcionar, porém na hora que eu executo tenho que passar uma mensagem e cada mensagem é diferente em cada execução, porém sempre pega a última mensagem passada, tentei fazer o mesmo esquema, porém não funciona com a mensagem.

Comment: Não vejo pq não funcionaria com uma mensagem, em que ponto do código você está a adicionar ela?

Answer (score 2):

Apesar da resposta do @Sergio apontar o problema, acredito que ela não o resolva, afinal o id utilizado no escopo interno é o mesmo do escopo externo.

Tentei simular o seu problema utilizando um setTimeout para simular a requisição AJAX.

```js
var btAdicionar = document.getElementById("btAdicionar");
var tmplLinha = document.getElementById("tmplLinha");
var tabContent = document.getElementById("tabContent");
var indice = 1;

btAdicionar.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var linha = tmplLinha.content.cloneNode(true);
  var input = linha.querySelector(".input");
  var output = linha.querySelector(".output");

  input.parentNode.dataset.indice = indice;
  input.textContent = indice;
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    output.textContent = indice;
  }, 2000);   

  tabContent.appendChild(linha);
  indice++;
});
```

```html
<input id="btAdicionar" type="button" value="adicionarLinha" />
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Input</td>
      <td>Output</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabContent">

  </tbody>
</table>

<template id="tmplLinha">
  <tr>
    <td class="input"></td>
    <td class="output"></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

O resultado que esperamos é que o valor do input seja igual do output, porém como o índice é pertence à um escopo mais amplo, então o mesmo acaba sendo atualizado antes que o output possa ser setado.

Neste caso então criamos um contexto para cada cada requisição:

```js
var btAdicionar = document.getElementById("btAdicionar");
var tmplLinha = document.getElementById("tmplLinha");
var tabContent = document.getElementById("tabContent");
var indice = 1;

var adicionarLinha = function (indice) {
  var indice = indice;
  var linha = tmplLinha.content.cloneNode(true);
  var input = linha.querySelector(".input");
  var output = linha.querySelector(".output");

  input.parentNode.dataset.indice = indice;
  input.textContent = indice;

  window.setTimeout(function () {
    output.textContent = indice;
  }, 2000);   

  tabContent.appendChild(linha);
}

btAdicionar.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  adicionarLinha(indice);
  indice++;
});
```

```html
<input id="btAdicionar" type="button" value="adicionarLinha" />
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Input</td>
      <td>Output</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabContent">

  </tbody>
</table>

<template id="tmplLinha">
  <tr>
    <td class="input"></td>
    <td class="output"></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

note, que dentro do método adicionarLinha, estou declarando novamente a variável índice, desta forma ela passa a possuir um valor diferente a variável índice externa.

```js
(function($){ 
  var enviarElemento = function (id) {
    var id = id;
    $.ajax(
      // configurações do ajax
    )
    .done(function(res) {
      fazAlgo(elementos[id], true);
    })
    .fail(function(res) {
      fazAlgo(elementos[id], false);
    })
    .always(function() {
      setTimeout(
        function(){
          removeElemento(elementos[id]);
        }, xTempo);
    });
  }
  
  $.fn.plug = function() {

    var elementos = new Array();
    var id = 0;
    var xTempo = 2000;

    elementos.push('novo elemento e id: ' + id);
    enviarElemento(id);
    id++; // sou obrigado a encrementar pois cada elemento tem que ter um identificador diferente

    var plugin = this;
    return this.each(function() {
      return plugin;
    }); 
  }; 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `+1` abordagem diferente da minha, ambas protegem o `id` de ser sobre-escrito.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro criares um objeto que guarde essas informações e que esteja num escopo protegido para guardares o elemento certo com o ID certo. Algo assim:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.plug = (function () {
        var worker = {}; // aqui fica em memória e vai recebendo IDs
        var id = 0;      // aqui e não dentro da função para não ser reiniciado como 0
        var elementos = new Array(); // acho que até isto devia estar fora, mas nõ sei como é o resto do teu código
        return function () {

            var xTempo = 2000;

            elementos.push('novo elemento e id: ' + id);
            worker[id] = elementos[id];
            id++;
            $.ajax( /* confi.*/ ).done(function (res) {
                fazAlgo(worker[id], true);
            }).fail(function (res) {
                fazAlgo(worker[id], false);
            }).always(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    removeElemento(worker[id]);
                }, xTempo);
            });

            // sou obrigado a encrementar pois cada elemento tem que ter um identificador diferente

            var plugin = this;
            return this.each(function () {
                return plugin; // o que faz esta linha?
            });
        }
    })();
})(jQuery);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/La5hpu6b/1/

Comment: acredito que ele tenha que criar um escopo diferente para cada requisição

Comment: @TobyMosque na minha resposta o `id` nunca é o mesmo. Vai incrementando sem ser reiniciado.

Comment: tudo bem, talvez eu não esteja conseguindo visualizar os escopos, e assim como você, não faço ideia do que este `this.each` no final realiza.

Comment: a linha this.each eu vi em um tutorial de como criar plugins jquery, dai lá dizia que essa linha serve pra que possa ser feito isso element.addClass('lala').meuPlugin().removeClass('lala'); no caso se não tivesse isso teria que vai cada chamada de função em uma linha diferente.

Comment: @MateusFMello [eu percebo a intenção](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15117/129) mas  `return plugin;` não faz muito sentido. `return this` sem o loop parece-me o ideal pois não estás a modificar nada. Entretanto, a minha resposta ajudou?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1**

Você pode ao invés de incrementar o id, gerar um número aleatório para identificar o item. Veja:

```
$.fn.plug = function() {

    /* Aqui gera o id aleatório */
    var id = String(Math.random() + 1);
    var elementos = new Array();
    elementos.push(id);

    $.ajax(
        // configurações do ajax
    ).done(function(res) {

        fazAlgo(elementos[id], true);
    }).fail(function(res) {

        fazAlgo(elementos[id], false);
    }).always(function() {
        setTimeout(
            function(){
                removeElemento(elementos[id]);
            }, xTempo);
        });

        var plugin = this;
        return this.each(function() {
            return plugin;
        }); 
    }; 
})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT 2**

Faça o seguinte então:

```
var ajaxManager = (function() {
     var requests = []; /* Array de requisicoes */

     return {
        addReq:  function(opt) { /* Adiciona requisicao */
            requests.push(opt);
        },
        removeReq:  function(opt) { /* Remove requisicao */
            if( $.inArray(opt, requests) > -1 )
                requests.splice($.inArray(opt, requests), 1);
        },
        run: function() {
            var self = this,
                oriSuc;

            if(requests.length) {
                oriSuc = requests[0].complete;

                requests[0].complete = function() {
                     if( typeof(oriSuc) === 'function' ) oriSuc();
                     requests.shift();
                     self.run.apply(self, []);
                };   

                $.ajax(requests[0]); /* Processa requisicao */
            } else {
              self.tid = setTimeout(function() {
                 self.run.apply(self, []);
              }, 1000);
            }
        },
        stop:  function() { /* Para requisicao */
            requests = [];
            clearTimeout(this.tid);
        }
     };
}());
```

Na chamada:

```
$(function() {
    ajaxManager.run(); 

    $("a.button").click(function(){ /* A cada click adiciona uma requisicao */
       ajaxManager.addReq({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'whatever.html',
           data: params,
           success: function(data){
              // do stuff
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Você pode adaptar conforme tua necessidade.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821064/stacking-multiple-ajax-requests-on-success-jquery

**EDIT 3**

Esse exemplo acredito que seja o que você precisa:

```
var ajaxManager = {
    arr : [],
    add : function(param, fn){
        var id = String(Math.random() + 1);
        arr.push({run : run(param, fn, id), id : id});
    },

    run : function(param, fn, id){
        $.ajax(param).done(function (res) {
            fn(res); 
            rem(id);
        }).fail(function (res) {
            fn(res); 
            rem(id);
        });
    }

    rem : function(id){
        $.each(arr, function(index, item) {
            if(id === item.id)
                delete arr[index];
        });
    }
};
```

Passa por parâmetro os dados da consulta e por ultimo uma função callback.

Comment: aqui alem de não está evitando a redefinição do id, você ainda está inserindo um segundo problema, uma possível (apesar de improvável) colisão de IDs.

Comment: @TobyMosque Colisão de ids não neh? Estamos falando em 0,0001 ou 0,0000001% de repetir o mesmo id? Acho mais fácil dos raios cairem no mesmo lugar. Frameworks com o jquery, por exemplo, utilizam essa abordagem de geração random. Não acredito que seja  o problema.

Comment: Infelizmente isso não soluciona o problema, só altera ele, mas vlw pela tentativa...

Comment: @MateusFernandesdeMello veja se o segundo exemplo atende

Comment: EmirMarques e @TobyMosque segue o código mais completo
http://goo.gl/e0lGd0
O que eu preciso é que quando os códigos dentro de done, fail ou setTimeOut identifiquem o elemento certo

Comment: @EmirMarques vou tentar essa segunda solução

Comment: @EmirMarques esse código não resolve pois quando ele remove as requests ele sempre identifica no código `requests.shift();`, `requests[0].complete`, `removeReq:  function(opt) {` e etc, no meu caso é dinâmica, é a requisição que terminar mais cedo vai remover o elemento que ela enviou

Comment: @MateusFMello veja essa última